# Display array value(dynamic) in alertbox onclick event using jquery

Tags: jquery

I populated an array in a dropdown list.

On Click of the item I want to display **colorList[i].Color** in alert box.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Xz9Hz/

**HTML:**

```
<div>   
<div id="DynaLoad">
</div>  
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var colorList = [
    { Color: "#FFFFFF", Name: "White"},
    { Color: "#202020", Name: "Grey"},
    { Color: "#DE2341", Name: "Red"},
];

    $('#DynaLoad').append("<select id='cList'></select>");
    for (i = 0; i < colorList.length; i++) {
    $("#cList").append("<option class='clr'>" +
    colorList[i].Name + "</option>");

    // Want to alert colorList[i].Color onClick of the particular selection

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the change event on cList using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as the select is added dynamically with script and its safe using on.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xz9Hz/2/)**

```
$('#DynaLoad').on("change", "#cList", function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the on() method description. Great help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after you create the select list:

```
    $('#cList').change(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xz9Hz/1/

Comment: Thanks for the change event :)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the change event with live in jquery.

```
  $(function(){
            $("#DynaLoad").live("change",function(){
               alert($(this).val()); 
            });
        })
```